# For what values $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\phi(m) | m$, where $\phi(m)$ is the Euler function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

I am working with elementary number theory and, although in theory the $\phi$ Euler function seems easy to understood, I am having some problemas making the exercises.

For example, in this question:

For what values $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\phi(m) | m$, where $\phi(m)$ is the Euler function,

I know two expressions to the function $\phi$ but, I tried to use them to solve this problem and I failed. Could someone help-me?

Thanks a lot.

Here is what I tried:

What I did was:
$\phi(m) = (p_1^{\alpha_1} - p_1^{\alpha_1 - 1})\ldots (p_k^{\alpha_k} - p_k^{\alpha_k - 1}) \Rightarrow$
$\frac{m}{\phi(m)} = \prod_k \frac{p_k^{\alpha_k}}{p_k^{\alpha_k}(1-\frac{1}{p_k})}= \prod_k \frac{p_k}{- 1 +p_k}.$
Then, I can't follow from here.

Comment: Use/deduce the fact that $\phi$ is multiplicative. Then notice that $\phi(p^{k}) = p^{k}-p^{k-1}$, whenever $p$ is a prime. Now by the fundamental theorem of arithemtic the problem is reduced to primepowers

Comment: Are they just $2^{\alpha_j} ?$

Comment: @TheOscillator Not so easily, for $3$ does not have the property, but $6$ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m=1$ works. Let $m=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ with $2\le p_1<p_2<\cdots <p_k$. Then

$$\phi(m)=p_1^{\alpha_1-1}p_2^{\alpha_2-1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k-1}\left(p_1-1\right)\left(p_2-1\right)\cdots\left(p_k-1\right)$$

$$\phi(m)\mid m\iff \frac{p_1p_2\cdots p_k}{\left(p_1-1\right)\left(p_2-1\right)\cdots\left(p_k-1\right)}\in\Bbb Z$$

If $k=1$, then $$p_1-1\mid p_1\implies p_1-1\mid p_1-\left(p_1-1\right)\implies p_1-1\mid 1\implies p_1=2$$

Then $m=2^{\alpha_1}$, and indeed it's a solution.

If $k\ge 2$, then we'll prove $p_1=2$.

Assume for contradiction $p_1\ge 3$. Then exists a prime $q$ such that

$$q\mid p_1-1\mid p_1p_2\cdots p_k\implies q\mid p_1p_2\cdots p_k\implies$$

$$ \left(\left(q\mid p_1\right) \text{ or } \left(q\mid p_2\right) \text{ or } \ldots \text{ or } \left(q\mid p_k\right)\right)\implies q\in\{p_1,p_2,\ldots, p_k\}$$

But then $q$ is too large to divide $p_1-1$. Contradiction.

Therefore $p_1=2$. Then $$\frac{2p_2\cdots p_k}{\left(p_2-1\right)\cdots\left(p_k-1\right)}\in\Bbb Z$$

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $p_2-1\ge 2$. Then

$$p\mid p_2-1\mid 2p_2\cdots p_k\implies p\mid 2p_2\cdots p_k\implies p\in\{2,p_2,\ldots, p_k\},$$

so $p=2$, because if $p\ge p_2$, then $p\nmid p_2-1$.

Therefore $p_2-1=2^h$ for some $h\in\Bbb Z^+$, so

$$2^h=p_2-1\mid 2p_2\cdots p_k\implies 2^{h-1}\mid p_2\cdots p_k$$

But $p_2\cdots p_k$ is odd, so $h=1$, so $p_2=3$.

Assume for contradiction $k\ge 3$. Then $4$ divides the denominator of $\frac{2p_2\cdots p_k}{\left(p_2-1\right)\cdots\left(p_k-1\right)}$ but not the numerator, so $\frac{2p_2\cdots p_k}{\left(p_2-1\right)\cdots\left(p_k-1\right)}$ is not an integer. Therefore $k=2$.

Then $m=2^{\alpha_1}3^{\alpha_2}$, which is indeed a solution.

Answer: $m\in\{1,2^t,2^a3^b\},\, t,a,b\ge 1$.

Comment: Why $\phi(m)$ has this expression? On my knowledge, $\phi(m) = (p_1^{\alpha_1} - p_1^{\alpha_1 - 1})\ldots (p_k^{\alpha_k} - p_k^{\alpha_k - 1})$

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi $$\phi(m)= \left(p_1^{\alpha_1}-p_1^{\alpha_1-1}\right) \left(p_2^{\alpha_2}-p_2^{\alpha_2-1}\right)\cdots \left(p_k^{\alpha_k}-p_k^{\alpha_k-1}\right)= p_1^{\alpha_1-1}p_2^{\alpha_2-1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k-1}\left(p_1-1\right)\left(p_2-1\right) \cdots\left(p_k-1\right),$$

because $p_i^{\alpha_i}-p_i^{\alpha_i-1}=p_i^{\alpha_i-1}\left(p_i-1\right)$.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi $$\phi(m)=\prod \left(p_k^{\alpha_k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)\right)\neq \prod \left(\frac{p_k^{\alpha_k}}{1-\frac{1}{p_k}}\right)$$

Maybe the LHS is the expression you wanted to write with the latex?

Comment: I wrote wrong. Look the edit I mad on the question. Is this correct now?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi It's correct. You can now continue from the part of my answer "if $k=1$...". I could've written the answer more clearly, but I wanted to make it short.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, was a typing problem. I will choose your answer but, for curiosity, can you follow from my trial?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi My answer already does that after "If $k=1$...". Notice $$\prod_k \frac{p_k}{- 1 +p_k}\in\Bbb Z\iff \frac{p_1p_2\cdots p_k}{\left(p_1-1\right)\left(p_2-1\right)\cdots\left(p_k-1\right)}\in\Bbb Z,$$

so my observation is the same as yours. Also, you shouldn't accept an answer you don't understand. I could make some things more clear, I just wanted to make it short.

Comment: Make more clear please.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi I've edited the answer.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Edited again, because I used $k$ for two different things.

Comment: thanks a lot @user236182. Now I understand exactly what you are saying. Thank you very much!